# Como posso criar um botão de edição para editar uma tabela criada dinamicamente no javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, dom

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Tabela dinamica</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
</head>
<body>
 <form action="" class="tabela">

  <label id="etiqueta" for="nome">Nome</label>
  <input required  type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">

  <label for="idade">Idade</label>
  <input required type="number" name="idade" placeholder="Digite sua idade">

  <label for="cidade" >Cidade</label>
  <input required type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="Digite a sua cidade">

  <button id="adicionar_dados">Adicionar Linha</button>

 </form>
 <div class="alerta"></div>

 <hr>

 <table border="2px solid" >
  <thead>
   <tr class="tabela" ">
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Idade</td>
    <td>Cidade</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody >
   
  </tbody>

   <hr>
 </table>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
//variaveis
var botao_adicionar = document.querySelector("#adicionar_dados");
var campo_idade = document.querySelector("input[name='idade']");
var campo_nome = document.querySelector("input[name='nome']");
var campo_cidade=document.querySelector("input[name='cidade']");

var corpo_tabela = document.querySelector("tbody");

var contTab=0;
//funcoes
function TabelaDinamica(nome,idade,cidade){

  this.nome=nome;
  this.idade=idade;
  this.cidade=cidade;


  this.mostrar_dados=function() 
  {
  console.log(" nome é"+this.nome+
   "a idade é"+this.idade+
   "e a cidade é "+this.cidade)
        }

this.criar_linha_tabela = function()
{

  var linha = document.createElement("tr");
  var campo_nome = document.createElement("td");
  var campo_idade = document.createElement("td");
  var campo_cidade = document.createElement("td");

  var inputNome = document.createElement("textarea");
  var inputIdade = document.createElement("textarea");
  var inputCidade = document.createElement("textarea");


  var texto_nome = document.createTextNode(this.nome);
  var texto_idade = document.createTextNode(this.idade);
  var texto_cidade = document.createTextNode(this.cidade);


  inputNome.appendChild(texto_nome);
  inputIdade.appendChild(texto_idade);
  inputCidade.appendChild(texto_cidade);

  campo_cidade.appendChild(inputCidade);
  campo_idade.appendChild(inputIdade);
  campo_nome.appendChild(inputNome);

  var botao_editar = document.createElement("input");
  botao_editar.setAttribute('type','submit');
  botao_editar.setAttribute('value','editar');

  var botao_excluir = document.createElement("input");
  botao_excluir.setAttribute('type','submit');
  botao_excluir.setAttribute('value','excluir'); 
  
  linha.appendChild(campo_nome);
  linha.appendChild(campo_idade);
        linha.appendChild(campo_cidade);
        linha.appendChild(botao_editar);
        linha.appendChild(botao_excluir);

        corpo_tabela.appendChild(linha);


        botao_excluir.addEventListener('click',excluir_dados);

        function excluir_dados(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         

         for(var element in corpo_tabela.children)
          console.log();
        }; 
    }

  };

function adicionar_dados(event){

 event.preventDefault();

 nova_tabelaDinamica = new TabelaDinamica(campo_nome.value,campo_idade.value,campo_cidade.value);

 nova_tabelaDinamica.criar_linha_tabela();

 nova_tabelaDinamica.mostrar_dados();
 

};

botao_adicionar.addEventListener('click',adicionar_dados);
```

consigo criar a tabela mais preciso colocar dois botões um para excluir e outro para editar mais não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer isso .

Comment: Recomendo que veja esses vídeos do [Rodrigo Branas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_y7rKxqPoyg&list=PLQCmSnNFVYnTD5p2fR4EXmtlR6jQJMbPb) ele explica tudo o que tu quer fazer mais umas coisas usando o AngularJS

Comment: O que o botão "Editar" tem que fazer ao clicar nele?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solução**

Seguindo as suas instruções, os inputs quando criados devem ser atribuidos `disabled` como atributo, para serem retirados pela função de editar.

**O código das funções ficaria assim:**

```
 botao_excluir.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var tr = this.parentNode;
        var tb = tr.parentNode;
      tb.removeChild(tr);

    });

    botao_editar.addEventListener('click', function(){
            var tr = this.parentNode;       

        for(var i =0; i< tr.children.length -2; i++){
                var td = tr.children[i];
            if(td.children[0].tagName = 'textarea')
            td.children[0].disabled = false;
        }

    });
```

**O código dos inputs ficaria assim:**

```
    inputNome.setAttribute('disabled',true);
    inputIdade.setAttribute('disabled',true);
    inputCidade.setAttribute('disabled',true);
```

> Você pode executar por aqui mesmo

.

```js
var botao_adicionar = document.querySelector("#adicionar_dados");
var campo_idade = document.querySelector("input[name='idade']");
var campo_nome = document.querySelector("input[name='nome']");
var campo_cidade=document.querySelector("input[name='cidade']");

var corpo_tabela = document.querySelector("tbody");

var contTab=0;
//funcoes
function TabelaDinamica(nome,idade,cidade){

  this.nome=nome;
  this.idade=idade;
  this.cidade=cidade;


  this.mostrar_dados=function() 
  {
  console.log(" nome é"+this.nome+
   "a idade é"+this.idade+
   "e a cidade é "+this.cidade)
        }

this.criar_linha_tabela = function()
{

  var linha = document.createElement("tr");
  var campo_nome = document.createElement("td");
  var campo_idade = document.createElement("td");
  var campo_cidade = document.createElement("td");

  var inputNome = document.createElement("textarea");
  var inputIdade = document.createElement("textarea");
  var inputCidade = document.createElement("textarea");
 
   inputNome.setAttribute('disabled',true);
    inputIdade.setAttribute('disabled',true);
    inputCidade.setAttribute('disabled',true);
    

  var texto_nome = document.createTextNode(this.nome);
  var texto_idade = document.createTextNode(this.idade);
  var texto_cidade = document.createTextNode(this.cidade);


  inputNome.appendChild(texto_nome);
  inputIdade.appendChild(texto_idade);
  inputCidade.appendChild(texto_cidade);

  campo_cidade.appendChild(inputCidade);
  campo_idade.appendChild(inputIdade);
  campo_nome.appendChild(inputNome);

  var botao_editar = document.createElement("input");
  botao_editar.setAttribute('type','submit');
  botao_editar.setAttribute('value','editar');

  var botao_excluir = document.createElement("input");
  botao_excluir.setAttribute('type','submit');
  botao_excluir.setAttribute('value','excluir'); 
  
    
    
  linha.appendChild(campo_nome);
  linha.appendChild(campo_idade);
        linha.appendChild(campo_cidade);
        linha.appendChild(botao_editar);
        linha.appendChild(botao_excluir);

        corpo_tabela.appendChild(linha);


        botao_excluir.addEventListener('click',function(){
         var tr = this.parentNode;
         var tb = tr.parentNode;
          tb.removeChild(tr);
        
        });
        
        botao_editar.addEventListener('click', function(){
          var tr = this.parentNode;            
            for(var i =0; i< tr.children.length -2; i++){
              var td = tr.children[i];
                if(td.children[0].tagName = 'textarea')
                td.children[0].disabled = false;
            }
        
        });

    
    }

  };

function adicionar_dados(event){

 event.preventDefault();

 nova_tabelaDinamica = new TabelaDinamica(campo_nome.value,campo_idade.value,campo_cidade.value);

 nova_tabelaDinamica.criar_linha_tabela();

 nova_tabelaDinamica.mostrar_dados();
 

};

botao_adicionar.addEventListener('click',adicionar_dados);
```

```html
<body>
 <form action="" class="tabela">

  <label id="etiqueta" for="nome">Nome</label>
  <input required  type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">

  <label for="idade">Idade</label>
  <input required type="number" name="idade" placeholder="Digite sua idade">

  <label for="cidade" >Cidade</label>
  <input required type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="Digite a sua cidade">

  <button id="adicionar_dados">Adicionar Linha</button>

 </form>
 <div class="alerta"></div>

 <hr>

 <table border="2px solid" >
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Idade</td>
    <td>Cidade</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody >
   
  </tbody>

   <hr>
 </table>


</body>
```

> Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O editar habilitaria a linha para poder mudar os valores

Comment: Tente utilizar o código da solução, caso não consiga, comente aqui que a comunidade te ajuda. @RodrigodeSouzasilva

Comment: Valeu cara muito obrigado !!!

Comment: Se funcionou, marque como respondida, ajuda na visualização de outras pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida.